# How can I do SQL query count based on certain criteria including row order

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I've come across certain logic that I need for my SQL query. Given that I have a table as such:

```
+----------+-------+------------+
| product  | valid | Date       |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1        | null  | 2016-05-10 |
| 1        | null  | 2016-05-09 |
| 1        | yes   | 2016-05-08 |
+----------+-------+------------+
```

This table is produced by a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product = 1 ORDER BY date desc
```

Now what I need to do is create a query to count the number of nulls for certain products by order of date until there is a yes value. So the above example the count would be 2 as there are 2 nulls until a yes.

```
+----------+-------+------------+
| product  | valid | Date       |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 2        | null  | 2016-05-10 |
| 2        | yes   | 2016-05-09 |
| 2        | null  | 2016-05-08 |
+----------+-------+------------+
```

Above would return 1 as there is 1 null until a yes.

```
+----------+-------+------------+
| product  | valid | Date       |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 3        | yes   | 2016-05-10 |
| 3        | yes   | 2016-05-09 |
| 3        | null  | 2016-05-08 |
+----------+-------+------------+
```

Above would return 0.

Comment: What about this don't you know how to do?   Do you know about the COUNT() function in SQL?

Comment: It is count but until a certain criteria is met in the order of the rows. So count the nulls until a yes value occurs after the rows are ordered by date.

Comment: That's just a WHERE clause with a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Correlated Subquery like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM products AS p1
WHERE product = 1 
  AND Date >
    ( -- maximum date with 'yes'
      SELECT MAX(Date) 
      FROM products AS p2
      WHERE p1.product = p2.product 
        AND Valid = 'yes'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select count(1) from table where valid is null and date > (select min(date) from table where valid = 'yes')
```

Comment: Your query doesn't take `product` into account.

Comment: It sounds like there will only be information for one product in the table at a time based on the query that is producing it and the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your logic provided covers all the possible weird and wonderful extreme scenarios but the following piece of code would do what you are after:

```
select a.product,
count(IIF(a.valid is null and a.date >maxdate,a.date,null)) as total  
from sometable a 
inner join (
select product, max(date) as Maxdate
from sometable where valid='yes' group by product
            ) b 
on a.product=b.product group by a.product
```